# Nginx: X-Accel-Redirect internal not working

Tags: nginx

This is my 'internal' setup on nginx:

```
location /issues/ {
    root /home/some_user/some_project/;
    internal;
}
```

When I comment out the "internal" part, Nginx serves the file in the "issue" folder and the files in it just fine. But even when it's enabled I am still unable to serve any files from the Python or PHP code:

```
# Python, outputs an empty zip        
import os
file_name = '12.pdf.zip'
response = HttpResponse()
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % t_str(file_name)
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
response['Content-Type'] = "application/zip"
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '12.pdf.zip'
return response

# PHP, does nothing
header("X-Accel-Redirect: 12.pdf.zip");
```

And these are sites-enabled/default and nginx.conf. 8000 is for Django and 81 is for PHP

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        # proxy / requests to apache running django on port 8081
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    }

    location /issues/ {
        root /home/some_user/some_project/;
        internal;
    }
}

worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
#    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;

    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

    include             /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

I've tried changing the Nginx config to alias, same thing. And tried all possible file paths. Can anyone see what's wrong? Or give me some pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why I couldn't get it to work before. Maybe the Nginx Wiki docs is wrong? This is how I solved it:

In nginx/sites-available/default:

```
   location /issues {
       root /home/ubuntu;
       internal;
   }
```

in views.py:

```
file_name = 'some.zip'
url = '/issues/' + file_name
response = HttpResponse()
response['Content-Type'] = ""
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
return response
```

And the full path the the Zip archive is:
/home/ubuntu/issues/some.zip

Answer (score 1):

```
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /issues/12.pdf.zip");
```

And 12.pdf.zip must be located in /home/some_user/some_project/issues/