# Unable to get nginx internal redirect to work

Tags: django, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and running nginx 1.4.6 as reverse proxy server to talk to my django backend which runs on uwsgi. I'm unable to get the internal redirect to work, that is, the request does not reach django at all. Here is my nginx configuration `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/default` file. Please let me know what is wrong with my configuration.

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        listen 8443 default_server ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        client_max_body_size    50M;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/nf.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/nf.error_log debug;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nf/nf.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nf/nf.key;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/northfacing;
        }
        location /media/ {
                internal;
                root /home/northfacing;
        }
}
```

Adding my uwsgi configuration.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/northfacing/reia
module=reia.wsgi:application
master=True
pidfile=/home/northfacing/reia/reia-uwsgi.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/home/northfacing/reia/log/reia-uwsgi.log
http = 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Adding my uwsgi startup script

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="northfacing"
PIDFILE="/home/northfacing/reia/reia-uwsgi.pid"

function start(){
    su - ${USER} /bin/sh -c "source /home/northfacing/nfenv/bin/activate && exec uwsgi --pidfile=${PIDFILE} --master --ini /etc/init.d/reia-uwsgi.ini"
}

function stop(){
    kill -9 `cat ${PIDFILE}`
}

$1
```

/home/northfacing/nfenv is my python environment directory.

Comment: From what URL to what URL do you want to redirect ?

Comment: Also, if you're using uWSGI, consider using native uwsgi protocol (`uwsgi_pass`) instead of `proxy_pass`.

Comment: What you do and what exactly does not work?

Comment: Are you running uwsgi on port 8000? Show your configuration and how you started it. And what URL are you using to access nginx?

Comment: Added my uwsgi configuration. What is not working is that, when a request comes to the projected uri /media, it should reach to django where the authentication verification runs and sets the response header. But, from nginx, upstream request does not reach django.

Comment: What? That's not what your configuration says at all. /media (like /static) is routed directly to the filesystem at /home/northfacing, and does not go through Django.

Comment: Tried with uwsgi_pass with the follwing changes in nginx configuration
        location / {
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

and uwsgi file

#http = 127.0.0.1:8000
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000

Still, protect url request does not reach the upsteam.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. If you see my configuration, static is directed to filesystem, but, /media has the "internal" redirect enabled.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you think "internal" has anything to do with redirecting to Django. That's not what it does at all, see [the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal).

Comment: Looks like people have already accomplished it. Please see this url.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547197/nginx-x-accel-redirect-internal-not-working

Comment: That question is doing the *opposite* to what you're asking. There they are requesting a URL under / which adds a header and redirects to the internal URL.

Comment: I have to use location /media/* instead of location /media/. Now, I see the request reaching the upstream django. I have to figure out the right X-Accel-Redirect parameters to send back to nginx.

Answer (score 6):

If you want django to handle permissions for accessing your media files, first thing to do is to pass all requests into django. I'm assuming that `/home/northfacing` is your project root dir (dir where by default manage.py will be placed), your static files are collected into `public/static` subdirectory in your project and media files are stored in `public/media`.

Basing on that assumptions, here is basic configuration for that behaviour:

```
server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/nf.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/nf.error_log debug;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nf/nf.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nf/nf.key;

    root /home/northfacing/public/;

    location @default {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;

        proxy_pass softwaremind_server;
        break;
    }

    location /static/ {
        try_files $uri @default; # just some simple default action, so you can show django's 404 page instead of nginx default
    }

    location /media/ {
        internal;
        error_page 401 403 404 = @default;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /maintenance.html @default; # you can disable whole page with simple message simply by creating maintenance.html with that message
    }
}
```

Simple explanation: all requests to urls in `/media/` are treated as internal, so nginx will serve 404, 401 or 403 error if entered directly. But in that location our proxy server (django in that case) is set as handler, so it will get request and will be able to check if user have access rights.

If there is no access, django can throw it's own error. If acces is granted, django should return an empty response with `X-Accel-Redirect` set to file path. Simple view for that can look like this:

```
class MediaView(View):

    def get(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise Http404

        response = HttpResponse()
        response.status_code = 200
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = request.path

        # all this headers are cleared-out, so nginx can serve it's own, based on served file
        del response['Content-Type']
        del response['Content-Disposition']
        del response['Accept-Ranges']
        del response['Set-Cookie']
        del response['Cache-Control']
        del response['Expires']
        return response
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
    url(r'^media/', MediaView.as_view(), name="media")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed configuration. One issue I still face is, any uri starts with /media/ does not get forwarded to upstream. It only does so when I have /media/* in nginx configuration. But, this makes a set of internal redirection cycle and eventually nginx throws 500 error. Still struggling on this.

Comment: Check my exact configuration, it works for me like a charm for nginx 1.9.3. You can also change `proxy_pass` to `uwsgi_pass` and reconfigure your uWSGI to use uwsgi protocol. Check also uWSGI and django logs (if any), maybe this 500 error comes from them, not from nginx.

Comment: Wish that I could give more than 1 upvote. After several hours of trying to figure this out, this answer helped me, and is the best config out of several other options, IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was my mis-understanding of how internal redirect works. According to the doc below
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal
an internal settings in the nginx configuration means that any request with that uri from the external source will be served with 404. It has to come only from the internal. In my case, the /media is used from the client as well. So, this was ignored by nginx. The following configuration worked.

In nginx, I have the following configuration. Note that /media is removed.

```
location /protected/ {
    internal;
    alias /home/northfacing/media/;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

and in python views,

```
def protect_uploads(request):
    if settings.DEBUG == False:
        response = HttpResponse()
        response.status_code = 200
        protected_uri = request.path_info.replace("/media", "/protected")
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = protected_uri
        del response['Content-Type']
        del response['Content-Disposition']
        del response['Accept-Ranges']
        del response['Set-Cookie']
        del response['Cache-Control']
        del response['Expires']
        logger.debug("protected uri served " + protected_uri)
        return response
```

Thanks for all your suggestions. That lead to different experiments and eventually a fix.